# How to make cut throught the mesh to make specific shape without having triangles

Tags: modeling

everyone i want to make the shape appear in the photo where i pointed on the mesh-the curve near theeye that extend to the side -:[image: the shape]

But i want to make it without having triangles i want as posible less triagles.And thanks in advance.

bleder file and refrence images: [zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yd6cz2JtabiDjI7MowUQj_tPf2YZhrKr/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should go from something like that to something like that:

[image]

This is your current topology, it doesn't follow the helmet shapes:

[image]

Use the knife to draw the shapes on the current topology and dissolve the useless edges, until you get something like that:

[image]

Then in front view, pull the edges in order to make the edges fit the shape:

[image]

Comment: thank you really smiple solution thank you again